Svelt app no longer executes the load function after build
When I run my Svelte app in the preview, it works fine, but as soon as I build it, the load function is no longer executed. To make sure, invalidateAll is executed every second for testing, this also no longer works in the app after building, but does in the preview.
the code of the pages shown:
export let data: PageData;

onMount(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        invalidateAll();
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
    };
});

$: console.log(data.ServerMessage);

The code from +page.server.ts in the same folder
let runsLoad = 0;

export const load: PageServerLoad = async () => {
    let runs = 0;
    let itemList: Coffee[] = [];
    try {
        console.log('load data from Server');
        [itemList, runs] = await getAllCoffees();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    return {
        coffeeList: itemList,
        ServerMessage: 'Load runs: ' + ++runsLoad + ' Query runs:' + runs
    };
};

and the code that is currently in another folder in a file called DB.ts.
let runs = 0;

// ----- connection functions ----- //
export const pool = mariadb.createPool({
    host: DB_HOST || 'localhost',
    user: DB_USER || 'root',
    password: DB_PASSWORD || 'ADMIN',
    database: DB_NAME || 'coffeeCloudDB',
    port: Number(MARIADB_DOCKER_PORT) || 3306,
    connectionLimit: 5
});

// ----- Helper functions ----- //
async function queryDB(query: string) {
    let conn;
    try {
        conn = await pool.getConnection();
        const rows = await conn.query(query);
        // console.log('queryDB rows:', rows);
        return rows;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    } finally {
        if (conn) conn.end();
    }
}

// ----- exporter functions ----- //
export async function getAllCoffees(): Promise<[Coffee[], number]> {
    const query = `
      SELECT c.id, c.coffee_name as name, c.description, false as favorite
      FROM CoffeeCloudDB.coffees as c
    `;
    let rows_return: Coffee[] = [];
    await queryDB(query).then((rows) => {
        rows_return = rows;
    });
    ++runs;
    return [rows_return, runs];
}

ave also tried to name DB file +page.server.ts but without success.
Here is an example image, where on the left in the console of the preview you can see how the couter counts up, while on the right you can see the web page after using yarn build and node build. I have also inserted a new entry in the DB, which can be seen in the preview on the left, but is unfortunately not loaded on the right.

I use the node-adapter, for the svelte app in the svelte.config.js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        env: {
            dir: './'
        },
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;

Additionally the vite.config.ts:
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    define: {
        'process.env': process.env
    }
});


and the package.json:
{
    "name": "coffeecloud",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "dev:with-host": "vite dev --host",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "test": "playwright test",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fontsource/fira-mono": "^5.1.0",
        "@neoconfetti/svelte": "^2.2.1",
        "@playwright/test": "^1.48.0",
        "@skeletonlabs/skeleton": "^2.10.2",
        "@skeletonlabs/tw-plugin": "^0.4.0",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^3.2.5",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^5.2.9",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.7.0",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^3.1.2",
        "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.15",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.5.0",
        "@testing-library/svelte": "^5.2.3",
        "@types/d3-color": "^3.1.3",
        "@types/d3-scale": "^4.0.8",
        "@types/eslint": "^9.6.1",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.13",
        "@types/node": "^22.7.5",
        "@vitest/ui": "^2.0.5",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
        "eslint": "^9.12.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.44.1",
        "globals": "^15.11.0",
        "jsdom": "^25.0.1",
        "prettier": "^3.3.3",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.2.7",
        "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.6.8",
        "svelte": "^4.2.19",
        "svelte-check": "^3.8.6",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.13",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
        "typescript": "^5.6.3",
        "typescript-eslint": "^8.8.1",
        "vite": "^5.4.8",
        "vitest": "^2.0.5"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "d3": "^7.9.0",
        "d3-array": "^3.2.4",
        "d3-color": "^3.1.0",
        "d3-hierarchy": "^3.1.2",
        "d3-scale": "^4.0.2",
        "d3-scale-chromatic": "^3.1.0",
        "layerchart": "^0.51.2",
        "mariadb": "^3.4.0",
        "mysql2": "^3.11.3",
        "svelte-awesome-slider": "^1.1.2",
        "svelte-ux": "^0.74.9",
        "text-encoding-polyfill": "^0.6.7"
    }
}




How do you run the built application?

I use yarn build to create the build folder and then node build to start the website. then Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000 appears and I use the website.

I can't even open a server with this IP binding. Builds are meant to be previewed with the preview script, i.e. npm run preview or the like (should not really change much except default host/port settings, though). Show your relevant configs, in particular the svelte.config.js which contains the adapter being used. If you have any additional plugins, also show the vite.config.ts. The package.json may also be helpful.

I have added the additional information, I use the adapter-node. This was also used in tutorials to dockerise the website

Don't see anything unusual there. Do you get the same result with the preview script/a different host binding? One thing to note: Environment variables may need to be loaded manually when running the application directly if you use an .env file (see docs).

I'm not sure if this is what you mean by the environment variables, but in DB.ts I import them with import { DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, MARIADB_DOCKER_PORT } from '$env/static/private'; . For testing purposes, I returned DB_USER in DB.ts in addition to runs, which was also printed correctly after the build. For the preview I am also not sure if I have understood it correctly, but if I use yarn build and then yarn preview, the data is still not updated on the website, if I use node preview after build, an error occurs.

yarn build is just a very specific shorthand for yarn run build, any other script defined in package.json requires yarn run <script-name>, i.e. here yarn run preview but you can also just use npm run preview; the package manager really should not matter in this case. Any environment variables from the $env/static/* modules will be baked into the output, so loading should not be an issue (though you should be aware that this means they cannot be changed later either, use the $env/dynamic/* modules for that.)
